# How to setup build number as a pipeline id in fastlane?

Tags: fastlane, fastfile

This is what I currently have in `Fastfile`:

```
def build(target_name)

  cocoapods
  cert
  sigh

  if ENV['CI_PIPELINE_ID']
    increment_build_number(build_number: "#{ENV['CI_PIPELINE_ID']}")
  end

  build_app(
    scheme: target_name,
    workspace: WORKSPACE_FILE_PATH,
    clean: true,
    output_directory: OUTPUT_PATH,
    output_name: target_name + '.ipa',
    export_options: {
      provisioningProfiles: {
        BETA_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER => BETA_PROVISIONING_PROFILE,
        DEMO_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER => DEMO_PROVISIONING_PROFILE,
        DEV_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER => DEV_PROVISIONING_PROFILE        
      }
    }
  )

end
```

But this code ends up with email from Fabric like this:

```
v3.3.21 (116)
```

instead of:

```
v3.3.21 (11741)
```

Why it doesn't assign pipeline id to build number?

[image]

It looks like it doesn't get inside if statement. Is it possible that `CI_PIPELINE_ID` variable is not visible for runner?